# how to develop In-app billing application for android apps

Tags: android, in-app

I developed a small android application. In that application I need subscription billing.
i integrated  dungeons sample code and added billing permissions. But still it showing item not found error. I uploaded apk into the development console and created products before adding the billing permission and sample code of dungeons to my application.

It is necessary to  add billing permissions before uploading the apk to development console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not Requried.

you may be not added product id to your application first add productId to your application it may be work

```
CATALOG = new CatalogEntry[] {
new CatalogEntry(monthly_product,R.string.subscription_monthly, Managed.SUBSCRIPTION),
new CatalogEntry(yearly_product, R.string.subscription_yearly,  Managed.SUBSCRIPTION), };
```

Here monthly_product,yearly_product are the productId's which created in google play store